# ¿No puede establecer valores booleanos en LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, conversión-de-tipos, booleano

No puedo establecer valores booleanos en localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem ("var1", true);
```

y al consultar por mi var1 me indica que es "undefined"

```
localStorage.getItem('var1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por defecto un valor **boolean** es convertido a **string** y debes evaluarlo como tal es decir algo así:

```
localStorage.setItem ("var1", true);
if(localStorage.getItem('var1') == 'true'){
  alert('verdadero');
}
```

Puedes revisarlo aca: [test valor Boolean](https://jsfiddle.net/mf6zbye5/1/)

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: [Cannot set boolean values in LocalStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263248/5215609)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 3):

Como mismo lo dijiste, no puedes. Pero si puedes evaluar el valor almacenado como un string y así saber si el valor es verdadero o falso. Es tan sencillo como:

```
const var1 = localStorage.setItem ("var1");

if (var1 == 'true') {

    // Verdadero

} false {

    // falso
}
```

O, si quieres convertir el valor a booleano:

```
const var1 = (localStorage.setItem ("var1") == 'true') ? true : false
```